# grep - removing a line that contains anything other than specified characters

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to find a way to delete any lines that contain characters other than what I specify. For example if I specify the characters a,e,i,o,u,r,s,t and I have a list of words

```
rat
tar
set 
meow
```

Then "meow" should be deleted from the list because it contains the letters "m" and "w", which I haven't okayed. Any ideas?

Comment: Does each of your line contain only one word??

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can do this:

```
$ grep -v '[^aeiourst]' file.txt
rat
tar
set
```

The pattern matches lines that contain any caracter not specified in the list. This is clearly explained in the `grep` manual page:

> A bracket expression is a list of characters enclosed by [ and ].  It matches any single character in that  list;  if  the  first character  of  the  list  is  the  caret  ^  then  it matches any character not in the list.  For example, the regular expression [0123456789] matches any single digit.

In addition to this, since what you want is to remove the lines that match that pattern the `-v/--invert-match` option is used. This is also well explained in the `grep` manual page:

> -v, --invert-match
>   Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you. It has the letters you specified in a set, enclosed by `[]`. `*` denotes that they can occur any number of times. `^` denotes the line must start with one of those letters, and `$` denotes it must end with it as well.

```
grep '^[aeiourst]*$' file.txt
```

Comment: This does the exact opposite the OP wants.

Comment: @jpalecek He wants `grep` to *delete* lines that contains letters **other** than the ones he specifies. This finds lines with *only* the characters he specifies.

Comment: `grep -v` - which inverts grep's logic

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesnt work, with or without the -v. When I dont put a -v, I still have a line in my output that has a question mark in it, which isnt one of the criterea. When I include it, everything is deleted. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user1161080 Using the command specified verbatim, with the file given above? I've run it and gotten rat, tar, and set. Hmm.

Comment: Okay sorry so the example I had given is very similar to the actual more complex project I'm actually working on. You're right, this works for the specific example I had given. For some reason it doesn't work in the context I want to use it although it's exactly similar, except a longer list of words with more accepted characters. Is there any scenario you can think of that your answer wouldnt work in?